# c++ polymorphism - accessing derived functions with base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

is there any way i can make the following work, or is there a work around? I must be missing something.

```
class base
{
public:
    int someInt;
    virtual void someFunction(){}
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void someFunction(){}
    void anotherFunction(){}
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    base* aBasePointer = new derived;

    aBasePointer->anotherFunction();

    delete aBasePointer

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need `anotherFunction()` to be virtual in base as well. Or call it through a pointer to derived. At the moment base knows nothing about this function.

Comment: What are the *real* functions? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It needs to be virtual AND defined in Base as well. It doesn't help if you add a new virtual function to Derived.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast<>` to *downcast* the pointer to the derived class (don't forget to test the result).

e.g

```
if ((derived* p = dynamic_cast<derived*>(aBasePointer)))
{
  // p is of type derived.
  p->anotherFunction();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, just the thing I was after.

Answer (score 1):

What Nim suggested will work, but if you're performing downcasts you almost certainly have a design problem. If you explain what you're trying to achieve maybe we can suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    derived* aDerivedPointer = new derived;

    aDerivedPointer->anotherFunction();

    delete aDerivedPointer

    return 0;
}
```

Other than that, you need to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.